# Mupltiple Qt project files in one Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, qt, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to have multiple Qt project files in a single Eclipse project?

The reason that I want to do this, is that I want to generate two different executables that have a large code base in common. If there is a better way to deal with this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to separate out the common parts of the code base into a separate library, be it a static library or a shared library. You'll then create an Eclipse project for the common parts and one for each of the executables.